# Images corrupted after copying

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Trying to copy images from remote server to use as thumbnails in my wordpress site. Some of this images become corrupted after copying.

Here's my code:

```
$url = 'http://media.cultserv.ru/i/1000x1000/'.$event->subevents[0]->image;
$timeout_seconds = 100;
$temp_file = download_url( $url, $timeout_seconds );

if(!is_wp_error( $temp_file )) {
  $file = array(
    'name' => basename($url),
    'type' => wp_check_filetype(basename($url), null),
    'tmp_name' => $temp_file,
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => filesize($temp_file),
  );
  $overrides = array(
    'test_form' => false,
    'test_size' => true,
    'test_upload' => true,
  );
  $results = wp_handle_sideload( $file, $overrides );
  if(empty($results['error'])) {
    $filename = $results['file'];
    $local_url = $results['url'];
    $type = $results['type'];
    $attachment = array(
      'post_mime_type' => $results['type'],
      'post_title' => preg_replace('/.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $results['file'] ) ),
      'post_content' => '',
      'post_status' => 'inherit',
      'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'post_parent' => $pID,
    );
    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename );
    if($attachment_id) {
      set_post_thumbnail( $pID, $attachment_id );
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot that shows what I mean (Left - original image; Right - copy on my server):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try using `$attachData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $filename);` and `wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attachData);` beofre calling `set_post_thumbnail` and see if the resulting image improves. Make sure to `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );` somewhere on the script as well.

Comment: The problem is that the image, accessible by url stored in $local_url is already corrupted. It's before the attachment is created.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your `download_url( $url, $timeout_seconds )` function is not working properly (you don't get to catch network/other errors, that's why you have corrupted images), also I don't think that the timeout parameter is really needed to download an url...

To fix this it's better to rewrite this function into something like this :

```
function download_url($url)
{
    $saveto = 'temp.jpg'; // generate temp file
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $raw = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return false;
        // you probably have a network problem here.
        // you need to handle it, for example retry or skip and reqeue the image url
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    if (file_exists($saveto)) {
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto, 'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
    return $saveto;
}
```